Unable to connect to SQL Server on Podman container using `localhost`
I'm having trouble connecting to a SQL Server instance running inside a Podman container. The server is hosted at the localhost address.
Setup details: I've installed SQL Server using the following docker-compose.yml file:
name: mssql
services:
  server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=some password
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      - C:\dockers\mssql2017\volumes\data\:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - C:\dockers\mssql2017\volumes\secrets\:/var/opt/mssql/secrets
     

Problem
When using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I can successfully connect to the server using the IP address 127.0.0.1 (with no SQL instance specified). However, the connection times out when I try to connect using localhost.
Troubleshooting steps:

Ping Test: When I ping localhost, it correctly resolves to ::1 (the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1).
> ping localhost
Pinging <my machine name> [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms


Docker Desktop: if I run the same SQL Server setup on Docker Desktop instead of Podman, it works without any issues.


Suspected cause:
It seems that there might be a difference in how Podman handles networking, but I'm new to Podman and can't pinpoint the exact issue. Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

I'm unsure how networking unifies (if at all) ::1 with 127.0.0.1. Does your /etc/hosts file include entries for both? It seems (!) that your host only supports the IPv6 localhost (::1) resolution and not the IPv4 (127.0.0.1). You can have both in /etc/hosts.

I tried adding and removing all combinations of localhost entries to the /etc/host file. Anyway, SMSS can connect with both ::1 or 127.0.0.1 address. The host file has the following comment that may be the root of the problem: # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.  Funny thing. Localhost always translates to ::1, despite I change host file or not. Host entries that target ip4 address translate to ip4 address. Anyway, the service binds to ip6 addresses, if I connect to ::1 it works.

I guess problem is about SQL server configuration. Named pipes are not enabled by default. So maybe it is not accepting localhost for this reason.
It may be easier to use IP address to access it. If you are accessing you SQL server from same container i believe it is OK to use local IP. If this is not working, your SQL server container could have some assigned IP address to access.
But this cannot be enough to solve this problem and we do not know your connection string but maybe you need to tweak a little bit your connection string too. I advise you to check this answer.
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database '*databasename*'. -Kubernetes with SQL Server and .NET8
Hope this helps.
